# How to make a grayscale button for a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope everyone's doing well.

I'm trying to create a grayscale button that changes the background of my whole website to grey, and when I click this button again, it returns to the original colour of the website.
I'm using JavaScript, HTML & CSS.
I've tried creating two functions in a button, which also didn't work out.

My code below

```
  <button onclick="grayscale()">Grayscale</button>
        <style>
        body
        {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
        filter: none;
        }
        </style>
        <script>  
      function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myImg").style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
      else function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("myImg").style.filter = "grayscale(0%)";
    }
}

</script>
</button>
```

Comment: What do you believe `else function` actually does? Why do you believe this to be valid syntax? Can you share the source upon which you're basing your implicit claim that it *is* indeed valid?

Comment: You're trying to call a function called `grayscale` but your function is called `myFunction`...

Comment: I don't have a source from which I took the else function, but because I've used javascript for a while now and I've used the else function, I thought it would be valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using an image to demonstrate the grayscale effect from Freepik](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-colorful-fluid-background_13295087.htm)

```html
<!-- Grayscale button -->
<button onclick="grayscale()">Grayscale</button>
<!-- An image to demonstrate the grayscale effect -->
<hr>
<img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-colorful-fluid-background_23-2148901720.jpg?w=2000" width="200">
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
  /* Remove the following three lines to remove animation */
  body {
    transition: filter 1s; /* Change "1s" to any time you'd like */
  }
  body.grayscale {
    /* grayscale(1) makes the website grayscale */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    filter: grayscale(1);
  }
</style>
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
  // Grayscale function
  function grayscale() {
    // Toggling the class "grayscale" on the body
    document.body.classList.toggle("grayscale");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use one function and use an if satement

```js
      function myFunction() {
     
      if(document.getElementById("myImg").style.filter == 'grayscale(100%)')
          document.getElementById("myImg").style.filter = "grayscale(0%)";
      else document.getElementById("myImg").style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
      
      
}
```

```css
body
        {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
        filter: none;
        }
```

```html
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Grayscale</button>
  
  <img id='myImg' src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function grayscale() {
  let img = document.getElementById("myImg");

  img.classList.toggle("grey");
}
```

```css
.grey {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* other styles if I want to add them */
}
```

```html
<button onclick="grayscale()">Grayscale</button>

<img src="https://picsum.photos/500" id="myImg" />
```

> the better, simple way is to use `.classList.toogle()` (this make you not using if/else)
> it will do the checking automatically for you. and also you can add more styling inside the class selector, and basically have more control (for example adding transitions or complex keyframe animation with the minimal js possible)
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList?retiredLocale=it

Answer (score 0):

Use the classList.toggle to toggle a class on and off.

```js
function toggleGrey() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").classList.toggle("greyscale");
}
```

```css
.greyscale {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="toggleGrey()">Grayscale</button>
<br><img id="myImg" src="https://placekitten.com/200/287" alt="">
```